# setInterval or setTimeout inside an .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code that will call a function by passing the parameters taken from a XML file. Once the parameters are passed to the function ,this function will write the contents in a DIV.
The problem that I am having is that the function should write once per time and only every 2 seconds.

This is what I have done so far, but unfortunately the function is called at the same time and the DIVs written in the same time. Looks like the setInterval does not work as I expect:

The function to be called once per XML data and every 2 second is:

```
obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
    obj.fitText(7.4);
```

The entire piece of code is:

```
var tocURL = "../broadcasted.xml";
$.get(tocURL, function(d) {
    $(d).find('tweet').each(function() {
        var cvdIndexId = $(this).find("index");
        var cvdTweetAuthor = $(this).find("author").text();
        var cvdTweetDescription = $(this).find("description").text();
        setInterval(function() {
            if (cvdTweetAuthor === "Animator") {
                obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                obj.fitText(7.4);
            } else {
                obj = $('#cvd_bubble_right').append(makeCvdBubble(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                obj.fitText(7.4);
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

The xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root bubbles="6">
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <author><![CDATA[@Liciiious]]></author>
        <description><![CDATA[#EveryoneLovesBeinsport (cc @beinsport @charlesbietry). #pureLIVE]]></description>
        <index>1</index>
    </tweet>
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Message]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[beIN Sport]]></author>
        <index>2</index>
    </tweet>
        <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <author><![CDATA[@Liciiious2]]></author>
        <description><![CDATA[#EveryoneLovesBeinsport (cc @beinsport @charlesbietry). #pureLIVE]]></description>
        <index>3</index>
    </tweet>
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Message]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[Animator]]></author>
        <index>4</index>
    </tweet>
        <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <author><![CDATA[@MAuricious]]></author>
        <description><![CDATA[#EveryoneLovesBeinsport (cc @beinsport @charlesbietry). #pureLIVE]]></description>
        <index>5</index>
    </tweet>
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Message]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[beIN Sport]]></author>
        <index>6</index>
    </tweet>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var tocURL = "../broadcasted.xml";
$.get(tocURL, function(d) {
    $(d).find('tweet').each(function(index) {
        var cvdIndexId = $(this).find("index");
        var cvdTweetAuthor = $(this).find("author").text();
        var cvdTweetDescription = $(this).find("description").text();
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (cvdTweetAuthor === "Animator") {
                obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                obj.fitText(7.4);
            } else {
                obj = $('#cvd_bubble_right').append(makeCvdBubble(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                obj.fitText(7.4);
            }
        }, index * 2000);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ncJaZ51Yx8GwsomxbmUc?p=preview)